# How to use jquery each function using a different counting method from the index counting method?

Tags: jquery

I have table and identified each row using the data-rowNumber method. Is it possible to start the jquery each method using a starting point with the data-rowNumber method, something like this.

```
       $("table tr").data-rowNumber(rowNumber).each(function()
       {
              // perform loop operations.....
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you're using the `data-row-number` attribute in HTML, like:

`<tr data-row-number="1"><td></td></tr>`

If so, your jQuery can do this:

```
  var startNum = 100;
  $("table tr").each(function()
       {
              if ($(this).data('rowNumber') > startNum) {
                 doSomething();
              };
       });
```

## EDIT

Turns out jQuery also has a greater than index [selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/). You can rewrite your code:

```
$("table tr:gt(100)").each(function(){
  doSomething();
});
```

Comment: thanks but i like your first solution because I'm using the database counting method with data-row...